# javascript async await with react. setState doesn't wait forawait

Tags: reactjs, async-await, ecmascript-2016

I am building a component tat get the members of a group and then download the image from the api. It uses async await in the componentDidMount and the photos come back correctly. however even though I am using async await. it doesn't wait for the images to resolve. Thus in setState it will return a promise.

my component:

```
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faUser } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import {
    GetGroupMembers,
    getImage
} from "../../../HttpRepositories/oneApiRepository";

class TeamCardPersonaMembers extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

state = {
    members: []
};

async componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    let members = await GetGroupMembers(this.props.teamId);

    const membersToSend = await members.map(async member => {
        const memberPhotoUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_ONE_API_URL}/api/users/${
            member.id
        }/photo`;

        let memberPhoto = await getImage(memberPhotoUrl);
        member.photo = memberPhoto;
        return member;
    });

    if (this.state.member !== "error" && this._isMounted) {
        this.setState({ members: membersToSend });
    }
}

render() {
    let members = [];

    console.log(this.state);

    if (this.state.members.length > 0) {
        this.state.members.map(member => {
            console.log("this is the member ", member);
            const memberImg = (
                <img
                    key={member.id}
                    src={member.photo}
                    alt={member.displayName}
                    className="team-card-persona-wrapper"
                    title={member.displayName}
                />
            );

            members.push(memberImg);
        });
    }

    return <React.Fragment>{members}</React.Fragment>;
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
}
```

}

console.log

[image]

export default TeamCardPersonaMembers;

any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard implementation of `map` does not await the callback passed to it. Resulting in the map call returning promises before the callbacks complete. You have two choices.

```
    const membersToSend = []
    for (const member of members) {
        const memberPhotoUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_ONE_API_URL}/api/users/${
            member.id
        }/photo`;

        let memberPhoto = await getImage(memberPhotoUrl);
        member.photo = memberPhoto;
        membersToSend.push(member);
    }
```

or to roll your own implementation of async map.

```
Array.prototype.mapAsync = async function (callback) {
  const output = []
  for (const el of this)
    output.push( await callback(el) ) <-- // Note the await on the callback

  return output
}
```

**Edit:**
Note that the above method executes the promises in sequence. As Jed points out, if you want to fire all the requests at once and wait for them to resolve,

```
const memberPhotos = await Promise.all(members.map(member => {
   const memberPhotoUrl = `${process.env.REACT_APP_ONE_API_URL}/api/users/${
            member.id
        }/photo`;

        return getImage(memberPhotoUrl);
}))
```

But this method could overload your network if there are too many requests, use with caution.

Comment: I choose the for loop. thanks for the help. guess I should have checked MDN for the async support. Cheers. will accept as answer when it's possible

Answer (score 0):

The `await` keyword only works on other async functions, or functions that return a `Promise`. So I don't think it makes sense to `await` on `members.map` like you are. That is just a normal sync function call. You need to set it up more like:

https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-await-array-map/